Was the true, overarching purpose of the vaults mentioned in any game after Fallout 2?
According to these sources, the true purpose of the Fallout franchise vaults was revealed in Fallout 2 and was to gather data to be used by the Enclave for their ultimate plan to save mankind.
Was this overarching purpose (not the purpose of each individual vault) mentioned in any other Fallout game, and if so, where?
Related posts:

Which Fallout game was it first stated that vaults were designed to conduct experiments?
Nukapedia "Vault" article
Nukapedia "Multi-generational starship" article

